# Docker yarn install stuck forever on M1 mac

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, macos

I have an M1 mac. I'm trying to build a docker image. I'm trying to build it on x86_64. Everything works fine until `yarn install`. It's stuck forever. Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:16

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install && aws --version

RUN mkdir code
WORKDIR /code

COPY package.json yarn.lock /code/

RUN yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile && yarn cache clean

EXPOSE 3000

ADD lib /code/lib

USER node
CMD ["node", "lib/index.js"]
```

If I don't set `--platform=linux/x86_64` it's failing on installing aws-cli. If I skip aws cli (and don't set platform), `yarn install` finishes within a minute, and the build succeeds.

I've also tried `--platform=linux/amd64`, same result.

What causes `yarn install` take forever?

Comment: (Why do you need the AWS CLI at all?  Can you use a Javascript-native AWS SDK instead?)